# Java - Get HTML Page Source code for Xpath query

Tags: java, android, xpath

I'm trying to do something simple (at least I thought it was simple) which is just pull the HTML code from a webpage, then create a DOM so I can then use xPath query on it.

I've found tons of examples how to do XML xPath in Java for local files, but NOTHING on doing it after pulling the source code from a website.

I've already learned how to do this in PHP which was the use of the following code...

```
$url = 'pagehtmlhere'
$output = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Supress Warnings for HTML5 conversion issue
$doc->loadHTML($output);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false); //Start Showing Errors

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);


$TitleString = "//h2[@class='title']/text()";
$BodyString = "//section[@id='body']/text()";
$ImageString = "//img[@id='iwi']/@src";



$titleQuery = $xpath->query($TitleString);
$title = $titleQuery->item(1)->nodeValue;

$bodyText = "";
$textQuery = $xpath->query($BodyString);

foreach($textQuery as $text){
    $bodyText .= $text->nodeValue . " ";
    }


$imageQuery = $xpath->query($ImageString);
$imageSrc = $imageQuery->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But i have absolutely NO clue how to do this in Java.

I've tried the following code....

```
            URL url = new URL(PageURL);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();


            //FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/employees.xml"));


            InputStream file = conn.getInputStream();
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

            XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();



           // System.out.println("*************************");
            String expression = "//div[contains(@class,\"carousel\")]/descendant-or-self::*[img]/img/@src')";
            //System.out.println(expression);
            String email = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
           // System.out.println(email);

            Log.d("email", email);
```

But of course I get an error at the line [InputStream file = conn.getInputStream();] because apparently this is incorrect way of doing it.

Can ANYONE help me with this with a working example? And please absolutely NO use of any HTML parser like HTMLCleaner or any crap like that.  I had spent hours and hours trying to get HTML Cleaner to allow "Asset" xPATH searches and it was a nightmare and I really don't want to deal with it and I don't want to have to depend on someone else's library at all.

Comment: from the doc, it looks like you need an inputsource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after a long time of looking.  I just needed to do a HTTP Connection and set the inputstream to that...

```
        URL url = new URL(PageURL);

        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setConnectTimeout(8000);
        c.setReadTimeout(15000);
        BufferedReader inn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                c.getInputStream()));
        Log.d("TAG", "-----> Got response on Thread" + String.valueOf(j));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = null;
        while ((l = inn.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(l);
        }
        inn.close();


        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(sb.toString());

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```